# Control-key behaves like F10

Tags: keyboard, mission-control

The control-key on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.8.4) has started behaving strangely. When I press it it acts in the same way as F10, bringing up Application Windows. This is a nuisance, as it affects key combinations that include the control-key.

I have no idea how this started, but I'd like to be able to stop it!

--Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

Open **Mission Control** in System Preferences. You should check if **Left Control Key** is being used to call Mission Control. Try to remove it from selections.

[image]